# Please explain what this "Priority Seat" represents

Tags: articles

I would like to understand what exactly this "Priority Seat" represents:

[image: Priority seat sign]

Image credit: [Southern Rail, UK](http://www.southernrailway.com/your-journey/accessibility/priority-seat-card/).

At first I thought this "Priority Seat" is an abbreviated form of "A Priority Seat"; "A" is simply omitted because it is a sign. But when I imagine a sign that reads "A Priority Seat" in this context (adjacent to a priority seat) I feel so wrong. The text wouldn't work to create the right nuance. So I had to drop this idea.

The next idea that I came up with was that this is an abbreviated form of "The Priority Seat." "the" is used here to talk about a particular type of things, not about a particular thing, just like "the" in "I want to play the guitar." But I can't be sure if my interpretation is correct.

Could anyone explain what this "Priority Seat" represents?